# save a doc file in php

Tags: php, doc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to generate doc file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516222/how-to-generate-doc-file-using-php)

I need generate a doc file with cakephp and save it to specific folder.because i want it to sent it as an email attachment dynamically...

i hava code that just generate and download the doc file..
    here is my code:

```
function getDoc($status=null,$cart_id=null)
  {
    $doc_company_data=$this->Company->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Company.user_id'=>$status)));
    $cart_order_data=$this->CartItem->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('CartItem.cart_order_id'=>$cart_id)));
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($doc_company_data);die;
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<b>Student Name: </b>".$userInfo['Member']['username'].'<br/><br/>';
    echo "<b>Email Address: </b>".$userInfo['Member']['email'].'<br/><br/>';
    echo "<b>Phone No: </b>".$userInfo['Member']['phone'].'<br/><br/>';
    echo "<b>Gender: </b>".$userInfo['Member']['gender'].'<br/><br/>';
    echo "<b>Date of Birth: </b>".date("d/m/Y",strtotime($userInfo['Member']['birthdate'])).'<br/><br/>';
    echo "<b>Address: </b>".$userInfo['Member']['road']." , ".$userInfo['Member']['street']." , ".$userInfo['Member']['city']." , ".$userInfo['Member']['state']." , ".$userInfo['Member']['country'].'<br/><br/>';
    echo "<b>Postal Code: </b>".$userInfo['Member']['postelcode'].'<br/><br/>';
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".$doc_company_data['Company']['name'].".doc");
    die();
}
```

Comment: A Word document is not merely an HTML file. You can't use HTML and just say it's a Word document. You need to create the proper syntax a Word file needs to contain. Look for a PHP library that can create Word documents.